# WCAG 2.0 - Combining adjacent image and with low contrast text link for the same resource

Tags: html, accessibility, usability

I'm designing a site where I'd like to use white text on different colored backgrounds. Unfortunately 2 of these backgrounds do not provide enough contrast to be WCAG 2.0 AA compliant.

The text is a "read more" link.

My question is - if the link has a title attribute does this make the text accessible hence WCAG AA complaint?

Further to this there will also be a small chevron image with alt tag enclosed in the  tag, does this redundancy work favourably for AA compliancy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are hitting two issues:

1. [Colour contrast](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html) of text on the background.
2. [Not describing links](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-refs.html).

Unfortunately title cannot be relied upon to convey information as some users cannot access it (for example people using the keyboard but can see the screen).

There are a few potential adjustments for the contrast issue:

- Applying an effect on the image (e.g. fading to black) on the section where text is.
- Applying an effect to the text, for example drop-shadow that increases the contrast.
- Choosing a different colour for text on the different images.

Otherwise you get into the situation of having to provide a style-switcher or personalisation options for increased contrast (assuming you want to meet WCAG2-AA).

I can't tell for sure the links don't describe their target, as if there is a heading above them that would provide context. However, 'read more' links does ring alarm bells.

If the chevron image has alt-text that is specific to the target page, that would help. For example:

```
<a href="#"><img src="file.gif" alt="Specific page title ">Read more</a>
```

NB: As alt text is read like inline text, include a space at the end.

Or if the order is the other way around:

```
<a href="#">Read more<img src="file.gif" alt=" about specific page title "></a>
```

Overall, if your box has a heading that describes the target page, I would make that a link and use a script to make the rest of the box clickable. (For example, the central boxes on http://ukwindsurfing.com/ )

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have adjusted the background colour using the Snook contrast analyser. I will also add descriptive alt tags to the chevron icons and consider making the entire div a clickable link. Cheers!